# Phonegap can't load remote content

Tags: android, ajax, cordova, phonegap-build

I've built an application in PhoneGap. I hand-code the application and upload it to phonegap build. 
I am currently testing it only on Android.
My app uses Jquery Ajax to load some content from my server.  This has worked PERFECTLY for the last 10 days.  Today, it just stopped.

My application cannot load any content from any server anymore.  This includes my Stylesheet (yes I prefer to host that on a server) and Google-hosted jquery.  I resolved these files problems by just adding jquery.min.js and a client-side style.css file but the $.ajax calls, which I relied on so heavily cannot become client-side.

My config.xml file has always had

```
<access origin="*" />
```

The file in question has this code in it:

```
<body onLoad="loaded();"> .........


function loaded(){
        alert("function called.");
        $.support.cors=true;
}
```

The code which is now failing looks like this:

```
var request = $.ajax({
               url: "http://myserver/somefile.php",
               method: "POST",
               data: { variable:value},
               dataType: "html"
             });

              request.done(function( msg ) { alert(msg); }
```

Would anyone else care to take a swing?

Comment: When you test the application with debugger, do you get any errors in adb console log?

Comment: Whenever I run the weinre debug, I just see "Targets: None"  and the page title is "Target not Connected".  So I have no capacity to debug this with Build debug tool

Comment: Stupid idea: try to put a try catch around your ajax call and request.done and show alert . May be there is an exception

Comment: Thanks, @Dilberted, I just added some error catching, as your suggestion.  Im getting a really generic error response "Error"  can't seem to get the error code though.

Comment: Did u try to log the whole exception object in alert message or just the property. Try alert (JSON.stringify (e)); -- e is the exception object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you installed the cordova-whitelist-plugin and added a Content Security Policy meta tag in your app? If not, that may be the issue. This plugin is required for Cordova 4.0 or above (Android & iOS) to access any non file:// URLs. https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist#content-security-policy

Comment: @GRY, following up on what Josh says, here are some more links to help you with the *white-list* plugin. Read #10 of [Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md)

Comment: Okay, so this is a little embarrassing, but I don't know how to add this plugin to my applicaiton.  I downloaded the source off of GIT, but there doesn't seem to be any example of adding the plugin.  Because I am using PhoneGap Build service, my other plugins simply appear as <gap:plugin  ... /> tags in my config.xml file.  How do hook this plugin into my project?

Comment: My Config.xml file just needed to load the plugin like this:
<gap:plugin name="com.indigoway.cordova.whitelist.whitelistplugin" version="1.1.1" />

Comment: Glad you were able to figure how to install the plugin with PhoneGap Build and that it solved your issue.